# regex for extracting text field

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex for extracting the text "28 N John Young Pkwy" from this html.

```html
28 N John Young Pkwy<br />              
<span class="locality">Kissimmee</span>,                    
<span class="region">FL</span>                  
<span class="postal-code">34741</span>
```

The address will vary each time so I'm looking for something that matches a generic text before the 
 tag.  The data format is always the same. I'm using JavaScript. I'm also looking at how it should be entered into the constructor.  Should it be something like:

```
var re = new RegExp("^.*?(?=<br />)");
var m = re.exec(textabove);
```

Comment: That regex would just be: `/28 N John Young Pkwy/`

Comment: Parse the HTML. What language are you working with?

Comment: How consistent is the data format? Is this snippet repeated several times in your HTML?  What does the surrounding HTML look like?

Comment: The address will vary each time so I'm looking for something that matches a generic text before the <br /> tag  - in response to the other questions.  The data format is always the same.  I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`/^[^<]*/` should work fine (you can verify on regexpal.com -- remove the slashes)

Edit: This will only work if there is no `<` in the data that you are extracting, but it is more efficient than the other answers that use positive look-ahead and/or laziness.

Edit 2: Here, have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnx2B/).

Comment: I don't think efficiency is much of a concern when matching a dozen characters, but +1 anyway for a solution that should work on practically any regex engine. Downside is, as you said, the desired text cannot contain a '<'

Comment: True, I just tend to use that syntax instead of greediness out of habit for that very reason

Answer (score 0):

This is not hard to do in javascript (version 1.5 or later):

```html
<div id='address'>
    28 N John Young Pkwy<br />              
    <span class="locality">Kissimmee</span>,                    
    <span class="region">FL</span>                  
    <span class="postal-code">34741</span>
</div>
```

```
var re = new RegExp(".*?(?=<br>)");
var m = re.exec($('#address').html());
alert(m[0]);
```

See the example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dnx2B/

Honestly, though, it's much easier without the regex:

```
alert($('#address')[0].firstChild.data); // returns exactly the same thing.
```

Comment: This looks like it will work.  How do you specifically enter it into the javascript constructor.  Like.    
var re = new RegExp("^.*?(?=<br />)");
var m = re.exec(textvariable);

Comment: Where is the `address` div in the original question?

Comment: @ach - There isn't one, but it's pretty safe to assume that the snippet of HTML provided is not the entire HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just the text before the `<br>`, something like this should work:

```
^(.*?)<br
```